# Combine Rows with similar values with one column different - Excel

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

I have a worksheet with many duplicate rows in which only one column is important that it differs.

[image: example data set]

Is there a function that will put each of the differing streams into new columns, with the header being the date of the stream?

Essentially, I would like to have each song as a row and the day's streams as a column in that row. Please see the attached image for the end result I would like to achieve.

[image: end result]

If this is possible in Python, that would be great as well, as I am pulling the data via a Python script using openpyxl.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have pandas install ?

Comment: Looks like a pivot table

Comment: If you define the pivot table in Excel then you openpyxl can update the sheet and tell Excel to refresh the pivot.